# Cross-Links Creation using xslt

Tags: xslt-3.0

I would like to give cross-links in the below XML using XSLT 3.0.

My Input XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book id="bk1">
<p>The heterogeneity of patients, various clinical manifestations and the dynamics of CS development cause problems with identifying its unified definition. However, CS can be usually diagnosed on the basis of clinical criteria which are easy to assess without the need for advanced hemodynamic monitoring Thiele et al., 2015. Increasing knowledge about (Perkins-Porras et al., 2009) patient characteristics and better understanding of the CS pathophysiology encourages researchers and clinicians to revise the classic definition. (Thiele et al., 2015; Werdan et al., 2012; Nadziakiewicz et al., 2007; Sobanski et al., 2010; Goldberg et al., 2009; Harjola et al., 2015; Holmes et al., 1995).</p>
</book>
```

Expected Output XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book id="bk1">
<p>The heterogeneity of patients, various clinical manifestations and the dynamics of CS development cause problems with identifying its unified definition. However, CS can be usually diagnosed on the basis of clinical criteria which are easy to assess without the need for advanced hemodynamic monitoring <a href="#bibThiele2015">Thiele et al., 2015</a>. Increasing knowledge about (<a href="#bibPerkins-Porras2009">Perkins-Porras et al., 2009</a>) patient <a href="#bibPerkins-Porras2019">Perkins-Porras, 2019</a> characteristics and better understanding of the CS pathophysiology encourages researchers and clinicians to revise the classic definition. (<a href="#bibThiele2015">Thiele et al., 2015</a>; <a href="#bibWerdan2012">Werdan et al., 2012</a>; <a href="#bibNadziakiewicz2007">Nadziakiewicz et al., 2007</a>; <a href="#bibSobanski2010">Sobanski et al., 2010</a>; <a href="#bibGoldberg2009">Goldberg et al., 2009</a>; <a href="#bibHarjola2015">Harjola et al., 2015</a>).</p>
</book>
```

If author name with `et al` or author name without `et al` also need to check and give tag. How to achieve this?

Comment: There is (in XSLT 2 and 3) `xsl:analyze-string` and in XSLT 3 additionally the `analyze-string` function that can both be used to process text with regular expressions and create nodes based on the match and non matches.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Thanks for your points and I'm newbie using `XSLT 2.0 and 3.0`. Could you please provide me sample `XSLT` code, so that it will very useful for me.

Comment: Look into any introductory book or tutorial on XSLT 2 or 3 first, for XSLT 2 there is a free copy of the book "Practical Transformation Using XSLT and XPath" available online at https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm. Plus the specs have examples e.g. https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#regex-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching on "names" is always difficult so the following might work for some examples but not for others:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
  
  <xsl:param name="author-pattern" as="xs:string">(\p{Lu}[\p{L}-]+)( et al.)?, ([0-9]{4})</xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="p//text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., $author-pattern)" mode="wrap-authors"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="fn:match" mode="wrap-authors">
    <a href="#bib{fn:group[@nr = 1]}{fn:group[@nr = 3]}">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: It's working fine. Thanks for provided XSLT 2.0 book link also.

Comment: Matching on NAMES it's working fine and how to do multiple NUMBER References CROSS-Links. Example: `[6, 9, 12]` should be `[<a href="#bib6">6</a>,  <a href="#bib9">9</a>, <a href="#bib12">12</a>]`? Could You please advise how to achieve this? Can I raise Separate Question for this? Pl. Advice.

Comment: @Balaji, raise that as a separate question and show what you have tried, now that you know about `analyze-string` matching based on regular expressions you should have the tools to write/work out the code on your own.

Comment: I have posted new question <<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74603912/numbered-reference-should-be-cross-link-using-xslt> with XSLT code and kindly advise to me. Thanks..