# Numbered Reference Should be Cross-Link using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I would like to give cross-links in the below XML using XSLT 3.0.

**My Input XML is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book id="bk1">
<p>The heterogeneity of patients, various clinical manifestations and the dynamics of CS development cause problems **[1]** with identifying its unified definition. However, CS can be usually diagnosed on the basis of clinical criteria which are easy to assess without the need for advanced hemodynamic monitoring **[6, 9, 12]**. Increasing knowledge about **[8, 11-14, 17]** patient characteristics and better understanding of the CS pathophysiology.</p>
</book>
```

**My Expected XML is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<book id="bk1">
<p>The heterogeneity of patients, various clinical manifestations and the dynamics of CS development cause problems **[<a href="#bib1">1</a>]** with identifying its unified definition. However, CS can be usually diagnosed on the basis of clinical criteria which are easy to assess without the need for advanced hemodynamic monitoring **[<a href="#bib6">6</a>,  <a href="#bib9">9</a>, <a href="#bib12">12</a>]**. Increasing knowledge about **[<a href="#bib8">8</a>, <a href="#bib11">11</a><a href="#bib12"></a><a href="#bib13"></a>-<a href="#bib14">14</a>, <a href="#bib17">17</a>]** patient characteristics and better understanding of the CS pathophysiology.</p>
</book>
```

**My XSLT look like below:**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
>  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
>  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
>    <xsl:output method="xhtml" />
>    <xsl:template match="/|node()|*|@*">
>      <xsl:copy>
>        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|*|@*" />
>      </xsl:copy>
>    </xsl:template>
>  
>    <xsl:param name="para-rgxp">
>      <text-patterns>
>        <bibnosingle>\[(\d+)\]</bibnosingle>
>        <bibunnumber>(\p{Lu}[\p{L}-]+)( et al.?)\s+\(([0-9]{4})\)</bibunnumber>
>        <bibnomultiline>\[(\d+),\s+(\d+)</bibnomultiline>
>      </text-patterns>
>    </xsl:param>
>  
>    <xsl:template match="div[not(preceding-sibling::*[matches(.,'^References')])]/text()" priority="10">
>      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{string-join($para-rgxp/text-patterns/*,'|')}">
>        <xsl:matching-substring>
>   <xsl:choose>
>     <xsl:when test="matches(.,$para-rgxp/text-patterns/bibnosingle)" >
>       <a href="#bib{regex-group(1)}">
>         <xsl:value-of select="."/>     
>       </a>
>     </xsl:when>
>         <xsl:when test="matches(.,$para-rgxp/text-patterns/bibunnumber)" >
>       <a href="#bib{regex-group(2)}">
>         <xsl:value-of select="."/>     
>       </a>
>         </xsl:when>
>         <xsl:when test="matches(.,$para-rgxp/text-patterns/bibnomultiline)" >
>       <a href="#bib{regex-group(3)}{regex-group(4)}">
>         <xsl:value-of select="."/>     
>       </a>
>         </xsl:when>
>     <xsl:otherwise>
>       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
>     </xsl:otherwise>
>   </xsl:choose>
>        </xsl:matching-substring>
>        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
>   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
>        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
>      </xsl:analyze-string>
>    </xsl:template>
> ```

`[1]` is working fine, but `[6, 9, 12]` and `[8, 11-14, 17]` is not working. How to get expected result? But [6, 9, 12] and [8, 11-14, 17] should be convert to [6,  9, 12] and [8, 11-14, 17]. But this is not converting. How to get the expect result through using XSLT 3.0.

Comment: Can you edit your question and present the code samples as code blocks so that they are formatted as such and (more) readable? I don't see any XML structure for the input or the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to identify the bracketed number references you can use a pattern, it might then be sufficient to process its content with two `tokenize` calls:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="num-ref-pattern" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">\[([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?(,\s*[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)*)\]</xsl:param>
  
  <xsl:template match="p//text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., $num-ref-pattern)" mode="num-refs"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="num-refs" match="fn:group[@nr = 1]">
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',\s*')">
      <xsl:if test="position() gt 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each select="let $refs := tokenize(., '-') return if ($refs[2]) then xs:integer($refs[1]) to xs:integer($refs[2]) else xs:integer($refs[1])">
        <a href="#bib{.}">{.}</a>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result e.g.

```
<book id="bk1">
<p>The heterogeneity of patients, various clinical manifestations and the dynamics of CS development cause problems **[<a href="#bib1">1</a>]** with identifying its unified definition. However, CS can be usually diagnosed on the basis of clinical criteria which are easy to assess without the need for advanced hemodynamic monitoring **[<a href="#bib6">6</a>, <a href="#bib9">9</a>, <a href="#bib12">12</a>]**. Increasing knowledge about **[<a href="#bib8">8</a>, <a href="#bib11">11</a><a href="#bib12">12</a><a href="#bib13">13</a><a href="#bib14">14</a>, <a href="#bib17">17</a>]** patient characteristics and better understanding of the CS pathophysiology.</p>
</book>
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine. What is the mean of `(-[0-9]+)`. I Know [0-9]+ Means any Numbers and 1 to Many times. But why we are using `-` before `[0-9]`? And What is the purpose of using `expand-text-"no"`?

Comment: @Balaji, you need to see the subpattern `(-[0-9]+)?` as the relevant part that is used to describe that the previous subpattern (i.e. `[0-9]+` a number) can be optionally followed by a dash `-` and another number i.e. for the ranges you might have with `11-14`.

Comment: @Balaji, as for the `expand-text="no"` on the `xsl:param`, well, that is just a safeguard I prefer to use in XSLT 3 where I start with `expand-text="yes"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` to be able to use text templates but for parameters like that one I don't want the content to be expanded e.g. if it had `{}` they would need to be used literally and not be evaluated as something containing XPath expressions.

Comment: I have appreciate your reply and explanation. Thanks a lot.